# VM Distributed Switch Networking on Same VMKernel Adapter

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

I have built 5 new hosts and I have added the management network from our distributed switch fine on an existing cluster but we have 2 more networks/port groups I need to add which must all be on the same vmkernel adapter. Everything I try just keeps adding the a new vm adapter with the port group assigned to it.

I have 4 NICs which have set policy to only use 2 dvuplinks and 2 as standby and they all show green. On the other hosts in the same cluster they have the port groups all on the one vm adapter which was set by a colleague who left end of last year. I have always added networking as a new adapter but this is not allowed so must go through the one adapter.

Answer (score 0):

A VMkernal adapter is equivalent to a NIC within the host/hypervisor. It is connected (assigned) to a port group, not vice versa. Also, it cannot be connected to multiple port groups but you can connect multiple VMK adapters to the same port group.

If you need VMkernel adapter functionality on more than one port group you need to create more VMK adapters. You can connect a new adapter to an already present port group or create a new one with it.